# How to use Apache Camel to read data from ClickHouse

Tags: java, jdbc, apache-camel, clickhouse

I am new to Apache Camel.

I use Camel SQL component to read data from ClickHouse. Below is my route.

```
from("timer://foofixedRate=true&period=60m").routeId("initCKSource").startupOrder(1).log([ckSource]querying...").to("sql:select datetime,date,id,idNumber from test_base;?dataSource=ckDS")
```

And this error occurred:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException: null
at ru.yandex.clickhouse.ClickHousePreparedStatementImpl.getParameterMetaData(ClickHousePreparedStatementImpl.java:442) \~\[clickhouse-jdbc-0.2.4.jar:na\]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.getParameterMetaData(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java) \~\[HikariCP-2.7.8.jar:na\]
at org.apache.camel.component.sql.SqlProducer$2.doInPreparedStatement(SqlProducer.java:120) \~\[camel-sql-2.23.0.jar:2.23.0\]
at org.apache.camel.component.sql.SqlProducer$2.doInPreparedStatement(SqlProducer.java:116) \~\[camel-sql-2.23.0.jar:2.23.0\]
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:605) \~\[spring-jdbc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE\]
... 12 common frames omitted
```

Comment: The error suggests that the ClickHouse driver does not implement [`PreparedStatement.getParameterMetaData()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#getParameterMetaData()). This method is required by the JDBC specification, which means throwing `SQLFeatureNotSupportedException` is not allowed! In other words, the ClickHouse driver is not a JDBC compliant driver, and you cannot expect generic JDBC tools that expect a JDBC compliant driver to work correctly. You should report a bug to ClickHouse that they need to fix their driver.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.But I can use the ClickHouse JDBC driver to read the data from ClickHouse without using the SQL component of Apache Camel. I think the combination of Apache Camel and ClickHouse JDBC driver is not good.